# How can I act on Core Data iCloud sync notification when the app is in the background?

Tags: core-data, icloud, background-process, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

I have an iOS app that uses Core Data with iCloud sync.  The app is working perfectly and syncing across multiple devices.  As part of my implementation my app is registered for the:

> NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification

This notification works perfectly with the app in the foreground, but what I would like to do is fire a local notification to let the user know that the iCloud data in the app has changed, whenever the app is in the background and a sync notification comes in.

I was under the impression that iCloud Core Data syncing continued in the background, but I am having trouble figuring this one out.

The code to fire a local notification is located in the function that is run when the above notification comes in, but it only works when the app is in the foreground.

Comment: How did you end up working around this problem? I'm looking to do something similar in my app to keep local notifications synced across devices based on the data in Core Data.

Comment: I have yet to figure this out.  Not sure it is possible.  Now all I do is simply pop an alert view any time the app is running and I receive the change notification.

Comment: Thanks @scooter - What is the significance of the alert view? I actually started a new question with some possible solutions I'm exploring over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251059/icloud-core-data-possible-to-get-nspersistentstoredidimportubiquitouscontentc/

Comment: It just reminds them that they have made changes to the database on another device.  Kind of like how iBooks tells you that you have read further along on another device than the one you are on and asks if you would like to jump to the latest page.  Not a requirement necessarily, but it does improve the user experience for my app.